# How to find the first peak in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to find the first peak's value in Signal of matlab.

I used a bandpassFilter and got the signal that I uploaded.

[image]

Then, I need to find the first axis 'x' value of peak. How do I find it? I tried using the 'findpeaks' function, but I didn't know it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use `max`:

```
[M,I] = max(A)
```

where `A` is your signal, `M` the value of the maximum and `I` its position in the array.

Then with `x(I)` you can retrive its x-coordinate (where `x` is the vector with the values on your x axis).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. If the first value isn't the max value, How can I find the first X-coordinate of value?

Comment: sorry, i do not get your question. do you have multiple maxima?

Comment: I mean, for example , the first value of peak is 0.8, and the second value of peak is 1.4, and the third value of peak is 1.3 . I need to find the first one automatically. What should I use a function in matlab?

Comment: maybe then you should use somenthin g along the lines of `[M,I] = find(A>threshold)` But it could be tricky to find a value of the threshold that is always valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
l=length(A)
for i=1:l-1
    if((A(i)-A(i+1))<0)
       continue
    else
       maxm=A(i);
       J=i;
       break
    end
end
```

Example

A=[1 3 7 6 8 9 12 10 8]

maxm =

```
 7
```

J =

```
 3
```

Comment: Please add an explanation, don't just post code alone